# Intel assembler/architecture documentation?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, x86, assembly

Would anyone know where the best "official" Intel documentation regarding the low level architecture/assembler internals would be? How the ESP works, the various registers- fetching values from RAM etc?

The Intel website is massive and I could find Agner Fog's website- but I was expecting a mammoth document for this.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute definitive reference is the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm), they're a great resource to understand the x86 architecture from a programmer's point of view (assuming you're comfortable with assembly already).

I would recommend that you download the combined volumes 1 through 3C (first download link on that page).  Volume 1 is a great overview of Intel's x86(-64) architecture, including various details regarding pipeline depths, register sizes, and available components in their processors.  If you need to refer to how specific instructions work, see Vol. 2, Ch. 3-4 (I believe binary instruction encoding is covered later in that volume as well).

---

For how the assembler itself works, that all depends on *what* assembler you're using in the first place.  You can easily find the assembler details for NASM/GAS on their respective websites, and there's tons of resources for MASM(32).  However, this is all independent of how the CPU works, so I believe what you're asking for should be covered entirely by the Intel documentation linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

A good overview about the available resources is the [StackOverflow x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

If you like to directly refer to Intel, the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) will satisfy all your needs. It's about 3800+ pages...

To analyze the performance of your software, the [Intel® Architecture Code Analyzer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer/) is very useful.

And if your processor is outdated (like one that does not support AVX-512 :-), you can use the [Intel® Software Development Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator/).